# what are some of J's unique features?

Tags: tacit-programming, j, apl

I come from a background of C, Fortran, Python, R, Matlab, and some Lisp - and I've read a few things on Haskell. What are some neat ideas/examples in J or other languages from the APL family that are unique and not implemented in more common languages? I'm always interested in finding out what I'm missing...

Comment: It can win [code-golf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)s easily :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

J has a very large set of operators that make it easy to gin up complex programs without having to hunt for a library. It has extremely powerful array processing capabilities, as well as iterative constructs that make explicit control structures irrelevant for most purposes -- so much so that I prefer using tensor algebra to declaring an explicit loop because it's more convenient. J runs in an interpreter, but a good J script can be just as fast as a program written in a compiler language. (When you take out explicit loops, the interpreter doesn't have to compile the contents of the loop every time it executes.)

Another fun feature of J is tacit programming. You can build scripts without explicit reference to input variables, which lets you express an idea purely in terms of what you intend to do. For example, I could define the average function as 'summing the terms in a list and dividing them by the number of entries in the list' like so:

`(+/ % #)`

or I could make a script that slices into a 2D array and only returns the averages of rows that have averages greater than 10:

`(10&<#])(+/%#)"1`

There's lots of other neat stuff you can do with J; it's an executable form of mathematical notation. Ideas generalize easily, so you get a lot of benefit out of learning any one aspect of how the language works.

Answer (score 5):

I think one of the most interesting aspects of J is that it is one of the very few non-von-Neumann languages that is even *remotely* mainstream.

Uhm. J mainstream? Well, yeah, compared to *other* non-von-Neumann languages it is! There are only *very few* non-von-Neumann languages to begin with, most of those only live inside some PhD thesis and were never actually implemented and those that *were* implemented usually have a userbase of 1 if even that. Generally, they are considered successful if at least one of the users doesn't sit on the same floor as the guy who invented it.

Compared to *that*, J *is* mainstream. In particular, J is based on John Backus's FP from his seminal Turing Award Lecture "*Can Programming be Liberated from the von Neumann Style?*" and it is AFAIK the only working implementation of it. (I don't think Backus ever actually implemented FP, for example.)

Comment: What is the difference between tacit style in J (which I presume is what makes it a non-von-Neumann language) and say point-free style in Haskell, stack languages like Icon and Factor, or pipelines of Unix shell commands?

There are many other languages where naming variables is considered bad style.

Comment: Jean Sammet catalogued some 1000+ programming languages back in the middle 70s, with the proviso that it wasn't a programming langauge worth counting unless it was used by at least 2 people other than the inventor.  That makes J pretty mainstream, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps not as unique as I make it out to be, but the top feature I can think of for J is implicit typing. It creates that nice abstraction level above execution and memory management to focus on the data being processed.

Suppose you need to store a number:

```
var1 =: 10
```

And it's done. Array?

```
var2 =: 4 8 15 16 23 42
```

Done. Oh, but wait, you need to divide that by 3.7? Don't bother with casting, just go for it:

```
var2 % 3.7
```

Being rid of that necessity to cast and manipulate and allocate is a tiny blessing.

Comment: Isn't this feature common in a lot of languages that offer vector-based arithmetic (e.g., Matlab, R, Python+Numpy)?

Comment: I think so too. It's not wholely unique, but it is an interesting feature.